# How to secure SFTP against symlink attack?

Tags: sftp, symlink

I've configured `SFTP` on my virtual machine, because I wanted to test how can I use `symlink` in order to access files outside from user home directory.

I've created user:

```
test:x:1003:1001::/var/www/test/public:/bin/false
```

Ownership and premissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  root root test

drwxr-xr-x test sftpusers public
```

Here is my `sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

#UsePAM no

Match group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory /var/www/%u
AuthorizedKeysFile /var/www/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

After that I had to login into my SFTP account and from there I did:

```
sftp> symlink / /public/root
```

I think most of the servers which use `SFTP` are configured in a similar way.

So, what can be done in order to prevent symlink attack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the symlink looks different in the `chrooted` environment and from the point of Apache/webserver view.

Unless the symlinks are necessary for the users, the obvious option is to forbid users connecting over `sftp` to create symlinks. You can do that using a parameter to `sftp-server`:

```
internal-sftp -P symlink
```

Comment: Yes that's one way of blacklisting symlink - http://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server, but I'm not sure if this is sufficient protection in this case...

Comment: If the user can not create a symlink, then you should be safe against this attack vector. If the users have other way accessing the filesystem they can create the symlink different way. On the other hand, you can also set up some other access control, such as SELinux, that could prevent Apache processes browsing the `/`.

Comment: this does not work in openssh version 6.1 (or earlier) but does work in version 7.4 (and presumably later);  i don't know which version of ssh/sftp got this feature

Answer (score -1):

Can someone please explain me how this could be exploited?